# Get file extension vba

Tags: vba, get

i need to store the extension from files in a variable in VBA,
What i've done for now is

```
file= Hello.pdf
extension = split(file,".")(1)
```

But sometimes my file could be like `file = 1.Filename.pdf` and so my extension variable is not working anymore...

could someone help me to find a solution to always get the extension from any file name even if they are multiples "." in it.

i had an idea it waas to read from right to left and get the string when it read a "."  but i'm new in vba and don't know where to look to start it....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim vFn As Variant

file = "Hello.pdf"

vFn = Split(file, ".")
extension = vFn(UBound(vFn))
```

Comment: thanks you,, how can i get the fil name from you code pls ?

Comment: Try this to get file name `Debug.Print Replace(sFile, "." & Split(sFile, ".")(UBound(Split(sFile, "."))), "")` or `Debug.Print Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".") - 1)`

Comment: @Melvinceylan,  `Filename = Replace(file, "." & extension, "")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Sub Get_Extension()
    Dim fso As Object, sFile As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFile = "Hello.pdf"
    
    Debug.Print Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "."))
    Debug.Print fso.GetExtensionName(sFile)
    Debug.Print Split(sFile, ".")(UBound(Split(sFile, ".")))
End Sub
```

To get the file name you can use that

```
Sub Get_Filename()
    Dim v, fso As Object, sFile As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFile = "1.Hello.pdf"
    v = Split(sFile, ".")
    ReDim Preserve v(0 To UBound(v) - 1)
    Debug.Print Join(v, ".")
    Debug.Print fso.GetBaseName(sFile)
    Debug.Print Left(sFile, (InStrRev(sFile, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
    Debug.Print Left(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".") - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: My lesson learned: `ReDim Preserve v(0 To UBound(v) - 1)` ([Option Base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-base-statement) related). I think I never needed it, but I surely would not have used `0 To`. Thanks.